# StreamCorruptedException in Java

Tags: java, android, exception

I've the following code:

```
public class SenderTask implements Runnable {
private DhtDto dto;
private ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
private Socket socket = null; 

public SenderTask(DhtDto dto){
    this.dto = dto;     
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),dto.sendTo());
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(dto);
        oos.close();
        socket.close();
        oos.reset();
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("sender","IOException: ",e);
    }
}

}
```

I'm getting a StreamCorruptedException at the following line:

```
oos.writeObject(dto);
```

When I searched, I saw answers saying that I should use only one ObjectOutputStream throughout the lifecycle of socket. But I don't understand what this exactly means. Can someone elaborate on what is the problem here and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've resolved it with some help from a classmate. The idea was to use a BufferedOutputStream in middle of Sockets and ObjectOutputStream. I don't properly know the reason though.